# Continuity in linear maps

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Consider the map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x,y)=(7x+x^4,\ 3x+4y+y^4)$. Then which of the following are true:

a) $f$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$.

b) $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ and all directional derivatives exist at $(0,0)$.

c) $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ but the derivative $\mbox{D}f(0,0)$ is not invertible.

d) $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ but the derivative $\mbox{D}f(0,0)$ is invertible.

Please explain and give formulae if needed.

Comment: I found fx(0,0)=(7,3) and fy(0,0)=(0,4), but don't know how to prove its continuity and differentiability.

Comment: Please make a genuine effort before posting the question.

Comment: K sir..I will take effort..sorry for inconvenience..

Answer (score 3):

Few hints:

a) the function $f(x,y)$ has polynomial components. This means that $f$ is of class $C^\infty$.

b) for a $C^1$ function all directional derivatives exist.

c,d) $Df(0,0)=\begin{pmatrix} 7 & 3 \\ 0 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$. Is this matrix invertible?

hope this helps